# How can I configure Rspec differently for request specs?

Tags: rspec

I have an Rspec configuration that I want to apply only to request specs. So far, the best solution I have is to use tags:

```
# in spec_helper.rb
config.before(:each, request: true) do
  # special settings
end
```

and

```
# in spec/requests/foo_spec.rb
describe "foo requests", request: true do
  # tests
end
```

This relies on my remembering to always tag these specs with `request: true`. **Is there a way to configure tests based on the folder they are in?**

(I'm using Rspec 2.14)

Comment: Haven't tested it but you could try to require a different spec_helper in your request/foo_spec.rb

Comment: The :type should be set to request for you automatically.

Comment: @FrederickCheung - yep, that did it. Want to delete your comment and make an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Rspec-rails sets the :type of each spec based on its location (this has to be one of the known types - you can't just make this up. The list is [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/directory-structure))

Rspec 3 no longer does this automatically, however you can restore the old behaviour by adding

```
config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
```

To your rspec configure block.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your special settings in a module, then you can specify the type inline to an include.

For example, this adds `Rack::Test::Methods` in request specs only:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rack::Test::Methods, type: :request
end
```